# cx_Oracle returning zero rows

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I am new to connecting to oracle db (version 19.3) through python 3.6. I am not getting any rows in return. Please tell me what am I missing here?

I think all connection is set up correctly because it's not showing any connection error or invalid password error. Tried using fetchall(), fetchmany(), rowcount etc. everything is returning zero. I tried printing the cursor object itself, which is working. I ran the query in my DB. I have Oracle DB 19.3 installed locally, using Oracle SQL developer for running SQL. Anything else I need to install?

```py
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect("username", "password", "localhost/orcl")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from emp')
for line in cur:
    print(line)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: This started working after a system restart, anyone who is reading this please restart once before scratching your head.

Answer (score 0):

After running

```
delete from emp;
```

your python program will display zero rows, as you report.

You may wish to INSERT one or more rows before running it.

You may also find the interface offered by [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to be more convenient.
It offers app portability across Oracle and other DB backends.
Cf https://developer.oracle.com/dsl/prez-python-queries.html